# MonoDevelop not launching with debugger attached

Tags: debugging, mono, monodevelop

I have a simple C# console application (on linux). Pressing play does nothing but build the project. My console application is set as "startup project". Right clicking the console project and clicking "Start Debugging Item" or "Run With > " also never does anything.

This is monodevelop 5.7.1.

Any ideas? This happens on multiple machines.

Comment: what version of Linux? what version of mono?

Comment: Sounds like you hit a similar issue, https://blog.lextudio.com/2012/07/how-to-troubleshoot-monodevelop-errors-on-opensuse/ If you don't have `libgnomeui ` installed, MonoDevelop won't be able to hook to Gnome.

Comment: turns out i was missing xterm dependency that the packages don't reference (in Arch/pacman).

Answer (score 0):

I am using Arch.

It turns out, the arch packages doesn't list xterm as a dependency, even though the "console window" that monodevelop uses requires it. `pacman -S xterm` solved my issue. Also, make sure you install the mono debugger packages (separate packages).